# Typescript React Native Property 'scrollToIndex' does not exist on type 'FlatList'

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have a component that scrolls a React Native FlatList:

```
<BottomCarousel
   ...
   onSnapToItem={(index) => {
      myList.current?.scrollToIndex({ animated: false, index });
   }}
/>
```

`myList` is a `FlatList` which is referenced with `useRef`:

```
const myList = useRef<FlatList<SomeList>>(null);
```

And I define the type of the list with:

```
type SomeList = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  ...
```

Nothing special here. It all works, but I get a TypeScript warning/error:

```
Property 'scrollToIndex' does not exist on type 'FlatList<SomeList>'.
```

Any ideas why? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Seems weird, are you sure you are importing `FlatList` from the right package? The only idea I have is that the import is wrong, because `FlatList` in `react-native` definitely has property `scrollToIndex`...

Comment: @AlexChashin you were spot on! I was importing the FlatList from react-native-gesture-handler. Thank you, you made my day!

Answer (score 3):

In case this help anyone, I got into the same issue and did correctly import from 'react-native'.

I was using typescript and did a wrong typing in the ref definition.

Old code:

```
const flatListRef = useRef(FlatList);
```

Changed into this and solved the issue:

```
const flatListRef = useRef<FlatList>(null);
```